# How to set maxAuthenticationAge in WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, saml

I'm new to Spring, and have just got SAML authentication with Spring Security and Okta working following [this tutorial](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/03/16/spring-boot-saml). However, Spring is rejecting SAML authentication older than 7200 seconds, and I'd like to extend that time.

The [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-advanced.html) say to set `maxAuthenticationAge` on the `WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl` bean, but...I have no idea how to do that.

Could someone give me an example or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, if you create all the setup, you use @Been in @Configuration class

```
// can put this been in any related config class, no need to create new one
@Configuration
public class Config { 
    @Bean 
    public WebSSOProfileConsumer getWebSSOProfileConsumerImpl(){
        WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl consumer = new WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl();
        consumer.setMaxAuthenticationAge(5000);
        return consumer;
    }
}
```

Or Xml (real project [xml demo](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/blob/master/uaa/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/saml-providers.xml#L217-L221))

```xml
<bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl"
      id="myWebSSOProfileConsumer">
    <property name="maxAuthenticationAge" value="5000"/>
</bean>
```

But in your case demo example uses `import static org.springframework.security.extensions.saml2.config.SAMLConfigurer.saml` and you need to inject `WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl` in it and according to [this pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml-dsl/pull/35) and its [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml-dsl/pull/35/commits/a1bb497815c9947b39248708f0f7261ed483867f#diff-89b3de9ea48ec9e27685a8b11a665d7aR137) you probably could do that like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/saml*").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .apply(saml())
            .webSSOProfileConsumer(getWebSSOProfileConsumerImpl())// <= here
            // ... rest of the setup
         
}


public WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl getWebSSOProfileConsumerImpl() {
    WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl profileConsumer = new WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl();
    profileConsumer.setMaxAuthenticationAge(5000);
    return profileConsumer;
}
```

The sad part is that it is not released yet and you probably will have to rewrite your version of [SAMLConfigurer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml-dsl/blob/master/spring-security-saml-dsl/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/extensions/saml2/config/SAMLConfigurer.java) or just copy paste the newer version from git repo and use it.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of solution I was hoping for. Bummer that it requires copy-and-pasting WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl from master, but it works! Thanks!

Comment: One thing: Oddly, SAMLConfigurer.webSSOProfileConsumer() (and the property itself) in master accepts WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl, not the interface WebSSOProfileConsumer. So the return type of your getWebSSOProfileConsumerImpl() can't be the interface. With that adjustment, it seems to work perfectly.

Comment: @jchamberlain yeah, fixed that in answer